# Xcode 4 libxml/... not found, new problem

Tags: libxml2, xcode4

I have searched the net and the consensus seems to be to add ${SDK_DIR}/usr/lib/libxml2 to the 'Header Search Paths'. I have done this and I can see in the project inspector that it expands the to correct full path name. I'm still getting errors that it can't find libxml/tree.h, etc. I have also tried using just /usr/lib/libxml2. That didn't work either. In both cases when I look at the command line generated by Xcode I don't see a -I with my Header Search Paths.

Comment: Xcode 4 is still under NDA - not for much longer hopefully - until then though you should not be discussing it in public forums.

Comment: I was able to fix the error by adding `"$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2"` (including double quotes) in **Targets > Build Settings > Header Search Paths**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try adding $SDK_DIR/usr/include/libxml2 to Header Search Paths.

Comment: where is this so called header search paths?

Comment: I saw $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2 instead. Not sure what's so special about xml that it deserves a special place among all the frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

See https://devforums.apple.com/message/379137#379137